# Euro Currency Symbol breaks XML document

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I am adding content to an XML document using PHP `File_Put_Contents` and then I am using Microsoft Word to open that document. The problem is, if I add the Euro currency symbol(`€`), then the document breaks, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: so you are saying if the user typed `€` as the input, i need to replace it with `&euro;` ?

Comment: `&euro;` is not a valid XML entity unless defined. It is available in (X)HTML and you can define it for your XML. It is not available in XML by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&euro;` is not a valid XML entity.

Trying to solve encoding issues with entities is a bad practice. Instead, make sure all your strings are properly UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that your strings are UTF-8 actually. The methods and functions in PHP will expect it as UTF-8 independent from the output. It is possible to work with other character sets/encodings but this is really complex.

If you create the XML using an XML API like DOM or XMLWriter, it will take care of the encoding as needed. In an UTF-8 XML document the `€` does not need to be encoded.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('price'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('€ 42.00'));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<price>€ 42.00</price>
```

However in an ASCII XML document the special character needs to be encoded as a numeric entity. Named entities like `&euro;` will not work. They are specific to (X)HTML and not XML.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('price'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('€ 42.00'));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<price>&#8364; 42.00</price>
```

The same is possible with XMLWriter:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');
$writer->writeElement("price", '€ 42.00');
$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->outputMemory();
```

If you generate the XML as text (usually not the best choice), you will have to take care of the encoding yourself:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', "\n";
printf('<price>%s</price>', htmlentities('€ 42.00', ENT_XML1 | ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"));
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<price>€ 42.00</price>
```

Comment: I am generating the XML as text, I tried using `htmlentities`, it prints out black space

Comment: Have you made sure that your input actually is UTF-8? If it is some other encoding/character the reading client will get some different byte that he can not understand..

Comment: you mean this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?, yes i do have that

Comment: No the processing instruction is an information for the browser/client that reads the XML. So that he knows the XML is encoded in UTF-8. The value of your variables/strings have to be UTF-8 in PHP, actually.

Comment: Please show me some example, i do have this `utf8_encode($value)` in all my strings, but it doesn't work

Comment: `utf8_encode()` converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. If your value wasn't ISO-8859-1 it will destroy it. You need to debug your application and like @evert wrote make sure that your strings are UTF-8.

Comment: so i just added this to my html document head tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and it started working fine. Now i do not know which answer to accept between @Evert and you, He got it right but did not provide an example, and you helped me until my issue was fixed

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to used '€'? And make sure you clean up your string using the snipped below:

```
$currentString = preg_replace("[^!-~ ]", '', $currentString);
```

Comment: @Reagan Gallant, how do you add &euro;??? In my answer it keep display the Euro symbol.